# Итератор под капотом

Tags: java, коллекции, итераторы

Есть два листа ArrayList и LinkedList. Получения элемента по индексу понятно как работает (3 способ перебора в прилагаемом коде). Как работает 1 и 2 способ, тое какая имплементация next у итератора? У 2 под капотом тоже итератор?

```
   List<Integer> linkedlist = new LinkedList<>();
   List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
   
   //1. Iterator
   Iterator<Integer> iterator = linkedlist.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       int i = iterator.next();
       //...
   }
   
   //2. Is iterator?
   for (int i : linkedlist) {
       //...
   }
   
   //3. Get by index
   for (int i = 0; i < linkedlist.size(); i++) {
       //...
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

### ArrayList реализация next()

`ArrayList` [под капотом](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Если отбросить служебные проверки и проч. то по сути в `Iterator` останется что-то типа:

```
public E next() {
    int i = cursor;  //cursor позиция в массиве
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}
```

Элементы хранятся в виде массива `Object[]`, соответственно извлечение элемента `next()` происходит через инкремент индекса.

### LinkedList реализация next()

`LinkedList` [под капотом](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java)

```
public E next() {
    if (!hasNext())
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
    lastReturned = next;
    next = next.next; //извлечение следующего элемента через ссылку
    nextIndex++;
    return lastReturned.item;
}
```

`LinkedList` элементы ссылаются друг на друга через `Node<E>.next/prev`, соответственно реализация `next()` естественным образом через извлечение данной ссылки.

Comment: Тое итератор все-равно использует доступ к элементу по индексу в случае ArrayList и перебор начиная с первого по ссылкам во втором случае. Как в случае LinkedList он находит первый элемент - точку отсчета?

Comment: Итератор не делает перебор при каждом обращении, он возвращает элемент, ссылка на который хранится в приватном поле `next`. Однако ссылка на первый элемент списка всегда хранится в соответствующем поле. Почитайте про связные списки в любом учебнике по алгоритмам, там всё это подробно описано.

Comment: @JavaJunior ссылка на первый элемент (голову списка) хранится в `LinkedList` - загляните в исходники

Comment: Ок, спасибо! Дабы не плодить вопросы, спрошу здесь, как происходит получение элемента массива по индексу? Что под капотом?

Comment: инструкция JVM `iaload` (для целого числа), на вход в стеке подается ссылка на массив, значение индекса, после исполнения инструкции в стек помещается результат значения из массива. То есть 2 раза `pop` (аргументы инструкции), потом сама инструкция, затем один раз `push`. [ссылка здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iaload)

Answer (score 1):

В случе если тип объекта справа от `:` реализует интерфейс `Iterable` то при проходе по элементам будет использован `Iterator`.

Если справа от `:` будет массив, то все развернется в обычный цикл с проверкой `a.length`, что мы не выходим за переделы массива

ArrayList и LinkedList оба реализуют `Iterable<E>` следовательно под капотом будет использован `Iterator<E>`

Подробней [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)